# google logging single output if not different from previous

Tags: c++, logging

I'm working with the google logging library and would like to have conditional logging. I have a code snippet like that

```
while(1){
  if(a == 1){
    LOG(INFO) << "some log text";
  } else if(a == 2){
    LOG(INFO) << "some other log text";
  } else if(a == 3){
    LOG(INFO) << "again some other log text";
  }
```

But instead of flooding my console I'd just to put out a new logline if it's different than the last one. Is there a feature supporting this kind of log with google's logging library or can I somehow modify it?

Comment: You could just check if `a == prev_a` and if so skip the logging block.

Comment: In this case yes, but my `a` is a pretty long conditional term not just a simple variable I could check for last state. What I could do is introducing a separate log variable, that's actually not even bad...

Comment: That still is pretty easy to solve.  Just store the result of the expression in a variable or wrap the expression in a lambda.  Most optimizers will optimize away that layer of abstraction but it keeps the code simple.

Comment: `LOG_IF(INFO, a != prev_a)` ?